# Java generics and interfaces, using types as method parameters

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have the following code:

```
public interface IDoWork<K extends AbstractKey,V extends AbstractClass> {
    V obtain(K key, V value);
}

public class AbstractKey {
    String id;
}

public class AbstractClass {
    String name;
}

public class ConcreteA extends AbstractClass {
    String attributeA;
}

public class DoWorkA implements IDoWork<KeyA, ConcreteA> {

    private static final DoWorkA INSTANCE = new DoWorkA();

    public static DoWorkA getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public ConcreteA obtain(KeyA k, ConcreteA v) {
        //do something in real life
        return null;
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        KeyA a = new KeyA();
        ConcreteA c = new ConcreteA();
        IDoWork<? extends AbstractKey, ? extends AbstractClass> instance =
                WorkFactory.getInstance().obtainInstance(a);
        instance.obtain(a, c);
    }
}

public class WorkFactory {

    private static final WorkFactory INSTANCE = new WorkFactory();

    public static WorkFactory getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public IDoWork<? extends AbstractKey, ? extends AbstractClass> obtainInstance(AbstractKey key){
        if(key instanceof KeyA){
            return DoWorkA.getInstance();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Case not handled");
    }

}
```

In the following code:

```
KeyA a = new KeyA();
ConcreteA c = new ConcreteA();
IDoWork<? extends AbstractKey, ? extends AbstractClass> instance = WorkFactory.getInstance().obtainInstance(a);
instance.obtain(a, c);
```

This line doesn't compile:

```
instance.obtain(a, c);
```

due to the nature of Java generics. I get the following error:

> The method obtain(capture#3-of ? extends AbstractKey, capture#4-of ? extends AbstractClass) in the type IDoWork is not applicable for the arguments (KeyA, ConcreteA)

Is there another way to do it? If omit the type parameters in

```
IDoWork<? extends AbstractKey, ? extends AbstractClass> instance =...
```

If I remove the type parameters from `IDoWork`... it works but I get a warning. Is there a way to fix that.?  I know that I can remove the type parameters from the interface and that will solve the problem but I find it handy to have the generics in order not to have to do casting + it brings clarity to the code since it's clear to see what each class uses. Depencendy injection is out of question because it's not available in the codebase I'm in.

Comment: You can't use: `IDoWork<KeyA, ConreteA> instance = WorkFactory.getInstance().obtainInstance(a);` ?  What's the code in `WorkFactory` - what does it bind as the generic type arguments?

Comment: I just added the WorkFactory class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have something that works, but is not very optimal:

If you define your WorkFactory this way:

```
public class WorkFactory {
    private static final WorkFactory INSTANCE = new WorkFactory();
    public static WorkFactory getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <K extends AbstractKey, V extends AbstractClass> IDoWork<K, V> obtainInstance(K key, V val) {
        if (key instanceof KeyA) {
            return (IDoWork<K, V>) DoWorkA.getInstance();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Case not handled");
    }

}
```

then your main method should work cleanly:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        KeyA a = new KeyA();
        ConcreteA c = new ConcreteA();
        IDoWork<KeyA, ConcreteA> instance = WorkFactory.getInstance().obtainInstance(a, c);
        instance.obtain(a, c);
}
```

I have changed `obtainInstance` to take the key and the val, to infer the types properly.

Comment: Thanks for a your answer but In my case the Factory should only use the key not the value

Comment: The folllowing code works but gives a warning:
        IDoWork instance = WorkFactory.getInstance().obtainInstance(a);

I would like to know how to get rid of this warning without @SuppressWarnings.

Comment: It should still work, even if you remove the value, from the signature, it will infer the type based on the LHS

Comment: It does but you included an  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") I would like to know if there's a way to do it in a clean way.

Comment: You are right @CarlAntaki , there is still this issue. I doubt if it can be helped though, as DoWorkA is a parameterized class whereas the obtainInstance is a generic method - even instanceof check bypasses the generic nature of the code. Let's wait for other answers, there should be a cleaner alternative